# Creating an enum in a database using Fluent - Error: Cannot convert value of type 'Type.Type' to expected argument type 'DatabaseSchema.DataType.Enum'

Tags: fluent

Model: is compiled without errors

```
enum Type: String, Codable, CaseIterable, RawRepresentable {
    case Unknown, Number, Text, Catalog
}

final class PivotObjectTemplatesPropertyTemplates: Model, Content {
    
    static var schema = "Pivot_ObjectTemplates_PropertyTemplates"
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?
    
    @Parent(key: "object_id")
    var object: ObjectTemplate
    
    @Parent(key: "property_Id")
    var property: PropertyTemplate
    ......
    
    @Enum(key: "type")
    var type: Type
    
    
    init() { }
    
    init(id: UUID? = nil, object_Id: UUID, property_Id: UUID, display: String = "?", note: String? = "?", tags: String = "", type: Type = .Unknown) {
        self.$object.id = object_Id
        self.$property.id = property_Id
        .....
        self.type = type
    } 
}
```

Migration:  is compiled with errors

```
struct CreatePivotObjectProperty: AsyncMigration {
    
    func prepare(on database: FluentKit.Database) async throws {
        return try await database.schema("pivot_object_property")
            .id()
            .field("object_Id", .uuid, .required, .references("object_templates", "id"))
            .field("property_Id", .uuid,.required, .references("property_templates", "id"))
            .field("display",.string)
            .field("note",.string)
            .field("tags", .string)
            .field("type",.enum(Type.self))    //*** Error
            .create()
        
    }
```

Error message:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Type.Type' to expected argument type 'DatabaseSchema.DataType.Enum'

Can someone please help me here and give a solution hint?

Comment: Add a language tag for more eyeballs.